# Determine current Linux user authority

Tags: c, linux, authentication

In C programs running on Linux it is simple to get what user it is run from: getuid()/geteuid(). But then PAM jump in the scene and open the question: what authority confirmed this user? Was it passwd/shadow file? Kerberos? NTLM? Something else?

Is there an API, GLIBC or kernel call to answer this?

I read credentials(7), pam(3) but found no answer.

Comment: I think you should look into utmp / utmpx, or last(1). It's basically a system for logging logins on linux and might be able to tell you where a login came from. But since by definition any suid program can become root or any other user, linux systems can have an arbitrary number of ways of gaining privileges, not all of which might necessarily write to these logs.

Comment: @user3296587 I look at `struct utmp` and see user name, pid, remote ip and host but nothing that would point to used PAM module. Have I missed something?